# HTML5 Input type check user enterted information

Tags: html

I've had a quick look and couldn't find what I needed. I expect it to be something simple. I have an input text box whose type is set to a number with range between 1 to 20. This works perfectly.

However, the user can just type in `abc` or `21`, which defeats the point. How can I set it so that the text box doesn't allow that?

Comment: With HTML alone you can't. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: Are you using Firefox? If so it is not supported.

Comment: google chrome and opera :)

Comment: I'll research the javascript, any pointers on where to start

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use "pattern"

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" />
```

Comment: use javascript for validations in this case is necesary

Answer (score 0):

input type="number" and "range" not supported in Firefox.

You might want to solve using javascript, or, if it is only a matter of 20 numbers (ie 1-20), why not use a drop down?

such as:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
</option>
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a 'number' type input element. It looks like this:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number

However, not every browser supports this, so you you may need to validate the input given by the user. This page will tell you which browsers support this feature:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp